# Angular mat-expansion-panel renders expanded, insensitive to clicks and without toggle icon

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am getting to know some basic MEAN-stack features and I'm following this tutorial (linked to the specific part of the video I have problem with): 
https://youtu.be/1tRLveSyNz8?t=5507 
Basically what I'm trying to do is inserting `<mat-expansion-panel>` inside a `<mat-accordion>` with a `<mat-expansion-panel-header>` and some simple `<p>` content below. 
What I'm getting rendered is an already expanded panel with the `<mat-expansion-panel-header>` and the `<p>` shown below, with no option to close and/or reopen it. It's basically dead. 
One thing I did differently than the guy from the tutorial is in app.module.ts file I imported the module according to the newest Angular documentation as follows:

`import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';`

My code in the component responsible for this expansion panel looks as follows:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      I am a header.
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>
      I am a paragraph.
    </p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatInputModule, } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PostListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

post-list.component.ts (.ts file of the component which contains my `MatExpansionModule`):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css']
})
export class PostListComponent {
  posts = [
    {title: 'First post', content: 'This is the first post\'s content.'},
    {title: 'Second post', content: 'This is the second post\'s content.'},
    {title: 'Third post', content: 'This is the third post\'s content.'}
  ]
};
```

Comment: if you add recently angular material to you project try rebuild project, is possible that the css file is not compiled.

Comment: Can you provide your `app.module.ts` file please, also your `ts` file of your component where you use the `MatExpansionModule` ?

Comment: Or check this article about angular material https://angularprojekt.blogspot.com/2019/09/angular-material.html

Comment: I edited my question and now it contains the files Alexis asked about.

Comment: Can you try to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` instead of `NoopAnimationsModule` ? And also `import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';` in your **post-list.component.ts**